# In a vue3 vite project, use axios post method to server, but the browser console netwrk show that it is a get method

Tags: express, http, axios, vuejs3, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS2FG.png)
I use thi axios request to post my server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN59Q.png)
From the picture, you can see that I have set the router to response post request.
When I send a request, the server response well, so that we can sure it is a post request.
However, when I use the browser console network to check this request, it shows that it is a get request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SPsx.png)

BTW，I config a proxy server in vite.config.js to solve the CORS, the request is send by the proxy server to my express server. I dont know whether it matter the problem.

Thanks for any response from this post.

For supplement, this is my request function which was encapsulated to create axios.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gft1p.png)

Comment: The browser is sending a GET, so the error presumably is in your request function where you call axios. But since you are not providing this function, I cannot be sure.

Comment: It just a axios.create() with config baseUrl.

Comment: Please add [code snippets instead of images](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)